# How do I replicate a graph like this in Victory?

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

Is it possible to replicate a graph like this in Victory Native? Whereby the amounts (100, 50, 50) are relative to each other and the price values are seperate.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible! check out the docs for Victory Groups https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-group/ and focus on having 4 Victory bars within that group. One for the relative amounts and then one for each independent price value.

I'm guessing it'll look something like this:

```
<VictoryChart>
    <VictoryGroup offset={10}>
        <VictoryBar
            data={[{ x: 1, y: 100 }, { x: 2, y: 50 }, { x: 3, y: 50 }]}
        />
        <VictoryBar
            data={[{ x: 1, y: 252 }]}
        />
        <VictoryBar
            data={[{ x: 2, y: 569 }]}
        />
        <VictoryBar
            data={[{ x: 3, y: 245 }]}
        />
    </VictoryGroup>
</VictoryChart>
```

Comment: This still adds padding for missing group values.